# Counting number of records filtering out a certain condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, group-by

I am trying to get a count of the number of unique incidents in a table that have only one session in them. We have a table called Session Tracking that stores the Incident number and also stores the previous status and current status for that session. I want to get a count of the number of incidents that have only one session, and I also want to get a count of the number of incidents that may have more than one session, but only if the following sessions start in closed and end in closed. Basically not counting the sessions where they don't change status in the aggregate list.

Example:

```
Incident ID  Start Status  End Status
1            Open          Closed
1            Closed        Closed
2            Open          Closed
3            Open          Closed
4            Open          Open
4            Open          Closed
```

I want to get the first three incidents because incidents 2 and 3 both had only 1 session each, and want to count the first incident because it had a session after it had already closed, and that second session doesnt count. The fourth incident won't be counted because it had more than one session where it was open.

This is the statement I am using, and think something might be off...

```
SELECT Incident, COUNT(Incident)
FROM Session_Tracking
WHERE NOT (Prev_Status = 'Closed' AND Current_Status = 'Closed')
GROUP BY Incident
HAVING COUNT(Incident) = 1
```

Comment: When you run this query, what results do you get?

Comment: I'm getting a list of Incidents and 1's, but I'm getting conflicting numbers comparing to without the WHERE clause. One month I am getting fewer numbers than the total number of sessions than with the WHERE clause, and the next I am getting greater numbers. It's strange, so I wanted to ask here if there would be a better way...and I am using Microsoft SQL Server

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using a reasonable database that supports window functions, you can do this by just counting things:

```
select SUM(case when numInIncident = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as Singletons,
       SUM(case when ClosedClosed = numInIncident - 1 and numInINcident > 1 then 1 else 0
           end) as RestClosed
from (select st.*,
             COUNT(*) over (partition by incident) as numInIncident,
             sum(case when startStatus = 'Closed' and endStatus = 'Closed' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by incident) as ClosedClosed
      from session_tracking
     ) st
```

The inner subquery counts the number of rows for each incident, and the numbe rof rows when the start and end statuses are both "closed".  The outer query applies this logic to get what the numbers you want.